# Extract Json attribute value from JsArray ( play )

Tags: json, scala, playframework, play-json

Following is snippet from my scala code. I am using play 2.4. Below is the ouput of my "message" val.

```
import play.api.libs.json._

              .map{ _ match {
                  case (Some( message :JsArray  ), x) => {
                       println(      message  )
                       println((message \\ "collectorId").map(_.as[Int]))
                   }
               }
```

> output :
>
> ["{\"id\":1,\"createdAt\":\"2015-11-11T16:18:58.789\",\"collectorId\":4}",
>   "{\"id\":5,\"createdAt\":\"2015-11-11T22:35:52.300\",\"collectorId\":5}",
>   "{\"id\":2,\"createdAt\":\"2015-11-11T16:21:05.377\",\"collectorId\":4}",
>   "{\"id\":3,\"createdAt\":\"2015-11-11T22:35:20.408\",\"collectorId\":2}",
>   "{\"id\":4,\"createdAt\":\"2015-11-11T22:35:38.602\",\"collectorId\":4}"]
>
> ListBuffer()

How to extract

> "collectorId"

value as Seq[Int]. When I execute the code     I get it as ListBuffer().

I found that JsObject should be there in place of JsArray.

> Thanks for the support guys. Here is how I was able to solve the issue.

```
case (Some( message :JsArray ), response ) => {
       (message \\ "collectorId").map{_ match { case JsNumber(s) =>  s.intValue() }
       }
}
```

Comment: Does `message \\ "collectorId"` returns to you `Seq[JsValue]`?

Comment: I didn't get the question. Do you want `List` instead of `ListBuffer`. If so just use `.toList`

Comment: How to extract "collectorId" value as Seq[Int]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
(message \\ "collectorId" map(_.as[Int]) toSeq
//> res0: Seq[Int] = List(4, 5, 4, 2, 4)
```

where `message` is `JArray`.